# Qt QVector - can I change by reference a value in an element?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a

```
QVector<structure> m_vector;
```

the structure has many fields, some of them fixed-dimension and some of them other dynamic QVectors..

I'm wondering if I can do this:

```
m_vector[4].another_vector[9].another_vector[2].field_in_the_structure = 2;
```

will the change be valid to the entire m_vector?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but wouldn't this be very easy to test yourself? Perhaps I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: To be honest, you're right, but my application is kind of highly nested now, so it won't be easy to test it. Besides I'm compiling without IDEs, so if someone has the right answer could save me a lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work the way you seem to expect it.